# How do you do design-time, strongly-typed data binding?

Tags: xaml, data-binding, winrt-xaml

Strongly-typed data binding means you get design-time autocomplete in the XAML tooling. How do you decorate your XAML controls and data templates so you have design-time, strongly-typed data binding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TestTemplate">
        <TextBlock xmlns:Models="using:App17.Models"
                   Text="{Binding Name}"
                   d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=Models:ColorInfo}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

Best of luck!